# magento 2 how to make custom attribute read only based on user

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to build something like there are some custom attributes, these custom attributes should be editable by admin only for other users it should be read only format.

Comment: Well there is no elegant way of doing so, but if you want I can update a code for doing so using css